# Move to row that starts with specific text in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a text box on my form that when you enter a customer code into it, my DataGridView will highlight the row in the grid if an exact match is found (see code below). However, I would like it if the DataGridView would display the first record that is the closest match. For example if a user enters just ‘C’ the grid would go to the first customer code that starts with a C. Please note I do not want to filter the DataGridView to achieve this. All records must remain in it.

```
Dim targetString As String = txtAccountCode.Text

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In CustomerDataGridView.Rows

If row.Cells(0).Value = targetString Then

CustomerDataGridView.ClearSelection()
CustomerDataGridView.Rows(row.Index).Selected = True
CustomerDataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 
CustomerDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Index

Dim selectedIndex = CustomerDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Index
CustomerDataGridView.Rows(selectedIndex).Selected = True
CustomerDataGridView.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).Selected = True

End If

Next
```

Comment: If by `the first customer code` you mean _the first from the top_, you can simply change your condition to `If row.Cells(0).Value.ToString().StartsWith(targetString) Then`. If, on the other hand, you mean _the closest to the current row_, you'd need to adjust your loop to start from the current row index (and maybe look upwards and downwards as well).

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, that resolved my issue!